# onClick button send data to Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

i made a quiz where you can test yourself then get a score, clicking on the button send score will submit the score to database.

**My Goal:** i need to send a Quiz score to database. I already added in model the score and in controller.js too, but i have no clue how to send score value to my database.

I tested with postman and it works perfectly, i received my score in my database, all what is remaining is the frontend part.

**Backend:**

*FormController.js :*

```
const form = require('../models/FormModel')

module.exports = {
    store: (req, res, next) => {
        let candidate = new form({
            fname: req.body.fname,
            lname: req.body.lname,
            score: req.body.score
        })
        if (req.file) {
            candidate.cv = req.file.path
        }
        candidate.save()
            .then(response => {
                res.json({
                    success: true,
                    message: 'Candidate added successfully!',
                    data: candidate,
                })
            })
            .catch(error => {
                res.json({
                    success: false,
                    message: 'An error occured!',
                    error: error,
                })
            })
    }
}
```

*FormModel.js:*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

    const formSchema = new Schema({
        fname: {
            type: String
        },
        lname: {
            type: String
        },
        score: {
            type: Number
        }
    }, { timestamps: true })

const form = mongoose.model('form', formSchema)

module.exports = form
```

**Frontend:**

*Quiz.js:*

```
const finishQuiz = () => {
        if (Questions[currQuestion].answer === optionChosen) {
            setscore(score + 1);
        }
        setGameState("endScreen")
        //maybe i need to add onclick event here?
    }
```

Comment: You need to have a route endpoint set up for the formController. Inside the finishQuiz method make a request to that endpoint with form data. If you have a route setup, then please share that.

Comment: hi.do you import cors and config in yours  file?

Comment: @HaroonAzharKhan i said that i tested my backend with postman and i got the score in my database. My issue is with front only. All i need is to send the score fron Front to Back.

Comment: You can make a request to the end-point/backend using fetch or any HTTP request library(e.g Axios)

Comment: You can learn about how to use fetch here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch